Put 3 tblr side by side
Currently, in my document, I put the 3 tables one above the other. I would have liked to try to put them side by side.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH01 & \ghspic{explos} & Explosif\\
            SGH02& \ghspic{flame}  & Inflammable\\
            SGH03& \ghspic{flame-O}  & Comburant\\
            SGH04& \ghspic{bottle} & Gaz sous pression\\
            SGH05& \ghspic{acid}  & Corrosif\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers physiques}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_physique}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH06 & \ghspic{skull} & Toxique\\
            SGH07 & \ghspic{exclam} & Danger\\
            SGH08 & \ghspic{health} & Grave danger\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers pour la santé}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_sante}
    \end{table}
    
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH09 & \ghspic{aqpol} & Danger pour l'environnement\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers pour l'environnement}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_environnement}
    \end{table}

\end{document}

I tested different solutions, notably inspired by the answer minipage with tables but the tables are intertwined.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH01 & \ghspic{explos} & Explosif\\
            SGH02& \ghspic{flame}  & Inflammable\\
            SGH03& \ghspic{flame-O}  & Comburant\\
            SGH04& \ghspic{bottle} & Gaz sous pression\\
            SGH05& \ghspic{acid}  & Corrosif\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers physiques}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_physique}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tblr}{
                vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
                colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] },
                colsep=3pt,
                row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
            }
            \toprule[blue]
            Code & Pictogramme & Signification \\
            \midrule[blue]
            SGH06 & \ghspic{skull} & Toxique\\
            SGH07 & \ghspic{exclam} & Danger\\
            SGH08 & \ghspic{health} & Grave danger\\
            \bottomrule[blue]
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{Pictogrammes dangers pour la santé}
        \label{fig:picto_danger_sante}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}

